# Python's cProfiler: method 'pop' of 'list' objects

Tags: python, profiling, snakeviz

I am trying to profile a python script I have. I run it like this:

```
$ python -m cProfile -o out.profile script.py
```

It runs well, I get a file called `out.profile` with profiling information, but I see that the biggest influencer in execution time is this:

```
~:0(<method 'pop' of 'list' objects>)
```

With 77% of the execution time. Here is a chart I got with `snakeviz`.

[image: snakeviz's output]

So, my question is:

**What part of the python API might be using 'pop' method of 'list' object? Because I am not calling `pop` explicitly anywhere in my script.**

Update: This is the CALL STACK I have on that method:

[image]

Comment: Do you want people to guess? Presumably you can actually *see* what line 39 of `import_movements-inserts.py` is, and have more insight into what objects are being used there.

Comment: I don't want people to *guess*. I am not asking how to make my script run faster. I would like to know, if there is a way to know (using `cProfiler`) the source of all those calls to `pop` since there are no explicit calls to that method anywhere in my code.